# Do power cords come with Amps

Tags: amplifier

I two amps that were my dads. An AER 60 Compact and a Henriksen Jazzamp. I don't see any power cords for them or compartments that might hold them. Do these type of amps come with the power cord when purchased new? Or is this something you purchase separately based on need or location? TIA!!

Comment: a quick google for AER60 shows it has a standard IEC 6A mains connector on it. You buy this in your locale so it has the right plug on the other end. The Jazzamp doesn't give up its secrets with a quick search, post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Image Search, both your AER60 amplifier, and your Henriksen Jazzamp have common IEC power inlet connectors. This is probably the most common kind of power cord connector currently available on this planet. It should be easy to find a cord that fits the power mains connector in your location.

IMPORTANT NOTE!:  Be sure to confirm that your gadget (amp or whatever) has its power set for whatever your mains voltage is (110V or 220V)  If you get that wrong you could end up with a serious problem.

[image: AER 60 Amplifier]

[image: Henriksen Jazzamp]

Comment: Thank you!! So if I sell either the buyer won't be looking for a cord, they will purchase as it fits their needs.

Comment: If you are trying to sell them, any buyer with a grain of sense is going to want to see them powered up before buying.